# MySQL: Use a LIMIT for a JOIN table added

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-5.7

### View

The view of the app contains a *page* which shows a bunch of carousels (each carousel = *a tag*), each of each should contain 5 *products*:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|Page                                 |
|+-----------------------------------+|
||Tag1                               ||
||+--------+ +--------+    +--------+||
|||Product1| |Product2| .. |Product5|||
||+--------+ +--------+    +--------+||
|+-----------------------------------+|
|...                                  |
|+-----------------------------------+|
||TagN                               ||
||...                                ||
+-------------------------------------+
```

### Database

#### pages

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(16) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

#### pages_tags

```
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| page_id      | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tag_id       | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| position     | tinyint(4) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE `pages_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `position` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `page_id` (`page_id`),
  KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `pages_tags_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`page_id`) REFERENCES `pages` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `pages_tags_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=663 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

#### tags

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=149 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

#### products_tags

```
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tag_id     | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE `products_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`),
  KEY `bouquet_id` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_tags_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `products_tags_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5698 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

#### products

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(128) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=335 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

### Goal

The goal is to get an output which will contain **all tags on the page, containing the max of 5 products each**.

### Query

Here is the query I've got before getting stuck:

```
SELECT t.name, p.name 
FROM pages a 
LEFT JOIN pages_tags a_t ON a_t.page_id = a.id 
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = a_t.tag_id 
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.id = (
  SELECT p_t.product_id FROM products_tags p_t WHERE p_t.tag_id = t.id LIMIT 1
);`
```

### Problems

1. Unable to use `limit 5`:

> ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

2. Unable to use `in` + `limit`:

> ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Help needed.

Comment: Hi and congratulations on your first question on dba! Could you please put your table structures in as DDL and not as the output of `DESC`? You can do this by running `SHOW CREATE TABLE foo\G;` - this will give them as `CREATE TABLE foo (...);` which is much more readable and allows for testing - you could also provide a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=2d22e7eb63bfc83a8842b6a181c10668) - thanks.

Comment: You must enumerate products over a group (page) then select products which have this number not above 5. For your MySQL version you may use ROW_NUMBER() emulation using user-defined variables. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmysql-5.7%5D+row_number and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql-5.7%5D+row_number

Comment: `products_tags` implies that a product can be in multiple tags.  Should the output dedup the list of products that is likely to occur?

Comment: > Should the output dedup the list of products that is likely to occur?  
Both output will work (unique list, duplicates).